# find and replace with correct sentence case sentences starting with lowercase. regex or sublime

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, sublimetext3

I have text where some sentences start with lowercase. i need to find them and replace with correct sentence case.some punctuations are incorrect. i.e. sentence starting after full stop without space.

i.e.

```
.this sentence
and this.also this. and this.This one is not.
```

replace with ->

```
.This sentence
And this.Also this. And this.This one is not.
```

sublime text 3 solution, regex , or python nltk solution is suitable.

i tried this solution. but it is slow and does not find sentences without space after full stop.

```
import nltk.data
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
text = """kjdshkjhf. this sentence
and this.also this. and this. This one is not."""

aa=sent_tokenize(text)
for a in aa:
    if (a[0].islower()):
        print a
        print "****"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern

```
^([^a-zA-Z]*)([a-z])
```

[image]

and use `$1\U$2` as substitution

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/LqiY2Z/2/)

***Update:-*** If you want to capture first lowercase after each `.` ( period ) you can use this

```
^([^a-zA-Z]*)([a-z])|(\.\s*)([a-z])
```

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/LqiY2Z/3/)

Comment: it does not find sentences after dot. and also find both uppercase and lowercase starting sentences

Comment: @alexprice you want it to match every first character after `.` ( period ) ?

Comment: @alexprice You mean [`something like this`](https://regex101.com/r/LqiY2Z/3/)  ??